# Gauss-Seidel Convergence Criterion

Tags: computational-algebra

The convergence criterion is $\| y^{k+1} - y^{k} \| < \varepsilon$
where $k$ is iteration number.

#### Question 1.

Is it possible to use simpler criterion
$$
\max_j \left(\left | y_j^{k+1} - y_j^k \right |\right) < \varepsilon
$$
where $j$ is equation number? If yes then

#### Question 2.

Probably for particular equations the condition
$$
\left | y_j^{k+1} - y_{j}^k \right |< \varepsilon
$$
will be fulfilled earlier than for others.
Is it possible to exclude these equations from the following iterations?

Answer (score 0):

Q1. I guess yes, because norms are equivalent in finite dimension (but the $\varepsilon$ will not have the same value.

Q2. For each iteration, you have to check that for each $j$, $|y_j^{k+1}-y_j^k|<\varepsilon$.  It could be that the max is obtained for one $j$ at one iteration, and for another one at another. So I don't think you can exclude some indexes $j$ in the criterion. Anyway, this criterion is computationally inexpensive so it shouldn't be a practical problem.

Comment: Q2. The question is not about computation of the criterion. The question is about computation of an equations. For example, if at the current iteration for equation j the criterion is fulfilled can I skip this j equation at all on subsequent iteration? It could be useful for large number of equations.

Comment: @user2351152 I believe I answered: a priori, I see no reason why $|y_j^{k+1}-y_j^k|<\varepsilon$ for some $k$ implies $|y_j^{k+2}-y_j^{k+1}|<\varepsilon$ (so I don't think you can skip this inequation).